# sed -i with quotes as first arg

Tags: bash, shell, sed

Using sed to fix whitespace in a git pre-commit hook, I ran into problems with the line:
`sed -i '' [the regex] [the file]`

Similar [comments by others](https://gist.github.com/larsxschneider/3957621) mention this inconsistency, and that taking out the quotes fixes the problem. That confuses me because I thought sed -i should take a filename as the parameter immediately following the flag. It may be a shell inconsistency; the gist I linked to is a .sh script and I'm using bash/centos.

What is the magic/issue behind the `sed -i ''` usage, and how does stripping out the `''` correct the problem?

Comment: sed in Mac needs `sed -i ''`

Comment: sed -i '' filename does nothing to the file. -E is used for giving more than one pattern operation on a file. i.e. sed -e 'pattern1' -e 'pattern2' filename OR you have to use "|" pipe (creating sub-shells).

Comment: BTW, you'd probably be better off using `ex` instead of `sed -i`: `ex` is POSIX-specified for use as an in-place editor, whereas the `-i` vendor extension to `sed`, not being standardized, isn't guaranteed to be supported at all, and when it _is_ supported, isn't guaranteed to work in any particular way.

Comment: ...or, of course, using `sed` without the `-i` and implementing the logic to overwrite the original after a successful operation yourself.

Answer (score 2):

As @avinashraj mentioned in their comment `BSD sed` *requires* an argument to `-i` whereas `GNU sed` makes that argument optional (and doesn't allow a space in a quick test on CentOS 5).

Because of that `GNU sed` behaviour using `sed -i '' 'script' file` is going to fail because it will assume `-i` has no argument, use `''` as the script to run, and use `'script'` as the first file to operate on.

Using `sed -i '' -e 'script' file` will solve the script-as-filename problem for `GNU sed` but then leaves it interpreting `''` as a filename.

Using `sed -i'' -e 'script' file` solves *that* problem.

I have no idea whether that is legal for `BSD sed` though. I expect `-e 'script'` is fine.

<strike>The question is whether it accepts the suffix smushed up against the `-i` flag.</strike>

Edit: As @CharlesDuffy accurately points out `BSD sed` cannot possibly accept `-i''` or it would accept `-i` as well since it cannot tell the difference between those in its argument processing (the empty string has already dropped away at that point).

Which means, unless I've missed something or `GNU sed` can actually accept `-i ''` correctly that I don't see a way to do this portably.

Comment: `sed -i'' -e 'script' file` is *precisely* the same as `sed -i -e 'script' file`; in the argv array passed to sed from the shell, it's not possible to tell the difference.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Good point. Wasn't thinking about that clearly. That makes this rather unfortunate.

Answer (score 0):

The below function defines a `sed_inplace` command that tries to do the right thing on any platform. (Note that it requires `bash` as shell).

```
sed_inplace() {
  local -a args=( "$@" )
  local sed_version
  if sed_version=$(sed --version 2>&1) && [[ $sed_version = *'(GNU sed)'* ]]; then
    # the GNU version
    sed -i "$@"
  elif [[ $sed_version = *"[-i "* ]]; then
    # assuming this to be the BSD version with -i
    sed -i '' "$@"
  else
    # the generic version
    local file=${args[${#args[@]} - 1]}
    local tempfile=$(mktemp "${file}.XXXXXX")
    if sed "$@" <"$file" >"$tempfile"; then
      mv "$tempfile" "$file"
    else
      local rc=$?
      rm -f -- "$tempfile"
      return $rc
    fi
  fi
}
```

Of course, you'd avoid this whole mess if you didn't try to use `sed -i` at all, and instead used `ex`.